# When to use SelectMany vs SelectManyAwait

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm just starting to make use of `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` in a simple CQRS implementation and composing some domain event handling pipelines.

I cannot find any documentation of the differences between `SelectMany()` and `SelectManyAwait()`. Is anyone able to provide an explanation of the difference between the two?

Comment: At first glance from AsyncEnumerable.AsyncOverloads, there isn't any difference: they both turn into identical calls to a method SelectManyAwaitCore ([SelectMany](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/master/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/AsyncEnumerable.AsyncOverloads.cs#L77), [SelectManyAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/master/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/AsyncEnumerable.AsyncOverloads.cs#L942))

Comment: By the looks of the source code @Rup mentioned, the only difference is `SelectMany` seems to be a flat async call controlled by `#if SUPPORT_FLAT_ASYNC_API`. It might be an internal trial thing as per [this github thread](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/pull/423#issuecomment-468797406). I think the best place to ask this question is to open a question on their github. Or you need someone working / worked on the project to answer.

Comment: BTW - very subjective, `SelectManyAwait` does not look like a good name.